# docker compose up vsftpd server exit with status code 2 at start and no logs available

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, vsftpd

I have a problem with docker container build on top of my dockerfile, indeed each time I use the command: **docker compose up -d**, the container created from that instantly exit with status code 2, and the command **docker compose logs ** give no output.

Here is the dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.18.0

WORKDIR /app

ARG APP_USER=ftp FTP_USER_USERNAME=dieriba FTP_USER_PASSWORD=ftp VSFTPD_VERSION=3.0.5-r2  OPENSSL_VERSION=3.1.1-r1


RUN apk -U update && apk add --no-cache vsftpd=${VSFTPD_VERSION} \
    openssl=${OPENSSL_VERSION} \
    openrc

COPY conf/vsftpd.conf /etc/vsftpd.conf

COPY conf/vsftpd.conf /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf

COPY conf/dtoure.42.conf .

RUN mkdir -p wordpress

RUN openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -days 365 -nodes -x509 \
    -config ./dtoure.42.conf \
    -keyout /etc/vsftpd/server.key -out /etc/vsftpd/server.crt

RUN chown ${APP_USER}:${APP_USER} /etc/vsftpd/server.key && \
    chmod 755 /etc/vsftpd/server.key && \
    chown ${APP_USER}:${APP_USER} /etc/vsftpd/server.crt && \
    chmod 755 /etc/vsftpd/server.crt

RUN adduser -D ${FTP_USER_USERNAME} && echo -n "$FTP_USER_USERNAME:$FTP_USER_PASSWORD" | chpasswd 

RUN echo ${FTP_USER_USERNAME} > /etc/vsftpd/user_list

RUN chown -R ${APP_USER}:${APP_USER} /etc/vsftpd && \
    chmod -R 755 /etc/vsftpd && \
    chown -R ${APP_USER}:${APP_USER} /etc/vsftpd.conf && \
    chmod -R 755 /etc/vsftpd.conf && \
    chown -R ${APP_USER}:${APP_USER} /var/lib/ftp && \
    chmod -R 755 /var/lib/ftp && \
    touch /var/log/vsftpd.log && \
    chown  ${APP_USER}:${APP_USER} /var/log/vsftpd.log && \
    chmod 444 /var/log/vsftpd.log

EXPOSE 20 21

USER ${APP_USER}:${APP_USER}

CMD ["/usr/sbin/vsftpd", "-D", "/etc/vsftpd.conf"]
```

Here is the vsftpd conf file:

```
# Allow local users to log in
local_enable=YES
pam_service_name=ftp

# Allow write access for local users
write_enable=YES

# Set the umask for uploaded files
local_umask=022

# Enable passive mode
pasv_enable=YES

# Specify the range of passive ports
pasv_min_port=30000
pasv_max_port=30010

# Enable FTP over TLS/SSL (optional, but recommended)
ssl_enable=YES
rsa_cert_file=/etc/vsftpd/server.crt
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/vsftpd/server.key
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=NO
require_ssl_reuse=NO
ssl_ciphers=HIGH

# Set the chroot jail for users (optional)
chroot_local_user=YES

# Allow users with chrooted access to write to their root directory
allow_writeable_chroot=YES

# Specify the FTP welcome message
ftpd_banner=Dieri FTP SERVER

# Limit the maximum number of clients
max_clients=10
max_per_ip=5

# Hide the FTP server's identity
hide_ids=YES

# Set the FTP root directory
local_root=/app/wordpress

# Allow symbolic links to be followed
follow_symlinks=YES

userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd/user_list
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_deny=NO
```

And here is the docker compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
    vsftpd:
      build:
        context: '.'
        dockerfile: Dockerfile-vsftpd
      image: vsftpd-image:v1
      ports:
        - 20:20
        - 21:21
      env_file : ../../../.env

networks:
  wp-nginx-mariadb:
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, It was because I was launching the app with a non root user, where vstfpd by default except root user to launch the app, you have to either add the directive `"run_as_launching_user=YES"` or let root user launch the application.